# How to place marker inside google maps polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, point-in-polygon

How to place marker inside polygon (this polygon already on map)? 
My thoughts are: find a way to inscribe for example circle to the polygon and find a center of this circle (it is not problem), but can't find way to inscribe circle.

Method getCenter() on LatLngBounds works not as expected, because math center of polygon can be out of this polygon visually.

Comment: Where about in the polygon do you want to place the marker? Do you want to place it manually or programically? How is the polygon generated? What have you done so far?. Have you a live link? These are just a few of the we need to help us help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to find the center of an irregularly shaped polygon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203135/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-center-of-an-irregularly-shaped-polygon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said [Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle) this is really duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203135/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-center-of-an-irregularly-shaped-polygon). So, for get center of polygon need to use programm realization of anything math algorithm for find center of polygon, there is no more easy way unfortunately.