# Using Sql Spatial Data (C#) to find the "visual" center of irregular polygons

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, polygon, bing-maps

I'm drawing regions (using `SqlGeometry`/`SqlGeography` and translating them to the WPF `LocationCollection` equivalent) on the Bing Maps WPF Control and needed to label them.  I got the labels drawn on the regions and attached them to the point found by `STCentroid()`.  Of course as you imagine this is a problem with the 'U' or 'C' shaped regions where the centroid ends up outside the region, which makes the label incorrect.

Is there a way using `SqlGeometry`/`SqlGeography` to find the "visual" center or perhaps find the largest circle that can fit in the shape and use that center?  I've tried [various methods](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/724/how-can-i-find-a-point-inside-a-polygon-in-postgis) using `STPointOnSurface()` but it seems that `STPointOnSurface()` always picks a point on the edge like so DCREHA (the label for the bottom dark green region always ends up on the edges:

[image]

Comment: Assuming that there is only one shape, one solution might be to find the open side and then move the label the opposite side until the label is within the shape. You might also do some filtering to remove some area. Or you might try to find the biggest concave area (I don't know if there are algorithms for that).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1203135/3628232

Comment: So where is the "visual center" of a U shape?

Comment: The center of largest circle that fits inside.  The example I posted is U-like, so very informally it seems like to me the largest circle that can fit in it would be in the south-west, encompassing Garner and touching the PDNUNN area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An almost identical question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1203135/3628232). In your case, the most relevant answer is probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34030389/3628232) one. The hard part of that answer is determining where to draw the line that splits the polygon into two equal areas. Therefore, I propose a slightly modified version below for SQL Server:

1. Use `STCentroid` to find the centre of mass
2. If this is inside the polygon (`STWithin`), then no need to process further; otherwise:
3. Determine the centroid of the polygon's bounding box (e.g. use `STEnvelope` to get the polygon's envelope and pass that as the argument to `STCentroid`)
4. If this centroid is within polygon (`STWithin`), it may be good enough (would need testing); otherwise:
5. Extend the line that connects the polygon's centroid and the envelope's centroid so that it extends to just beyond the polygon's envelope in each direction (may be easier in C# code, or see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104451/66066) for a PostGIS solution)
6. Determine the intersection points between the extended line and the polygon (`STIntersection`)
7. Find the nearest intersection point to the polygon's centroid point from step 1 (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx)). This point is an approximation for the "1st cut point" detailed in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34030389/3628232).
8. Find the nearest intersection point to the intersection point found above in step 7. This point is an approximation for the "2nd cut point" detailed in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34030389/3628232).
9. The mid-point of the line that connects the two intersection points will be inside the polygon, and should be a reasonable approximation for the "visual centre" of the polygon.

For instance, given the polygon for the DCREHA example above, the following GIF animates the procedure listed above (judged by eye - actual result will differ):

[image]

Comment: I'm gonna accept this as it is very close to what I ended up doing (and would work for anyone with a similar issue) and I appreciated the effort that went into it.  I went with casting 8 rays from the centroid (if not inside shape) to the NW, N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, took the intersection of those lines with the shape formed by the actual geometry and the viewbox, measured them and placed the label at the midpoint of the longest resulting line.