# How can I calculate a solid centerline from polygons in a KML file for use as waypoints in guiding a robot?

Tags: php, coordinates, kml

I have a KML file , coming from a tractor that contains the worked area of a
field. It divides the field in allot of polygons, each containing coordinates
to shape that polygon. I want to use that data for guiding a robot that detects
and removes weed from the corn field. Since i have this data, i don't need complex
systems to guide the robot since this high accuracy data is already available (2cm).

I need to calculate a centerline from a those polygons in the KML file, for use
as waypoints for the robot. Since the workedarea polygons are always 3m wide (corn planter
is 3m) , and my robot will be 1.5m wide, i should prefer to have 2 guidlines per .
But i'd be happy to get one decent centerline. i can work from there to add more.

This is one example placemark , with its coordinates of the polygon :

```
<Placemark>
  <name>WorkedArea</name>
  <Polygon>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
          3.503930725,51.106383112,0
          3.503908586,51.106378907,0
          3.503672366,51.106360783,0
          3.503569505,51.106356148,0
          3.503519129,51.106356295,0
          3.503467953,51.10636004,0
          3.503347383,51.106378471,0
          3.503297128,51.106384066,0
          3.503124894,51.106407317,0
          3.502982908,51.106418658,0
          3.50289805,51.106422361,0
          3.502897037,51.10644914,0
          3.502985213,51.106445405,0
          3.503130216,51.106433893,0
          3.503355477,51.106404768,0
          3.503478017,51.106386066,0
          3.503525883,51.106382742,0
          3.503572303,51.106382876,0
          3.503669887,51.106387524,0
          3.503902831,51.106405447,0
          3.503922577,51.106409402,0
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

this code refers to the followng polygon :
[Polygon image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0BkC.jpg)

The coordinates are in order from one side to the other
[Polygon image example waypoints order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvGbi.jpg)

I was able with some PHP code to get centers between two side by side coordinates ,but for that to work i need an even number of opposite coordinates, and that is not always
the case in highly bended polygons like the example

```
function getCenterLatLng($coordinates)
{
    $x = $y = $z = 0;
    $n = count($coordinates);
    foreach ($coordinates as $point)
    {
        $lt = $point[0] * pi() / 180;
        $lg = $point[1] * pi() / 180;
        $x += cos($lt) * cos($lg);
        $y += cos($lt) * sin($lg);
        $z += sin($lt);
    }
    $x /= $n;
    $y /= $n;

    return [atan2(($z / $n), sqrt($x * $x + $y * $y)) * 180 / pi(),  atan2($y, $x) * 180 / pi()];
    
}
```

Is there anyone who can point my in a direction to get a solid centerline?
Prefered PHP, but any code example will do. Thank you.

/* SOLUTION */

I came to the following script : It detects one long side of the polygon, and draws a point at 1.5m at a 90° bearing from the point compared to the previous point. That gives me a pretty accurate waypoint in the middle of the polygon. The script is still not perfect , but it's a good way to start from here.

```
function calculatePoint($point1, $point2, $distance)
{
    $aroundCorner = false;
    // Convert latitude and longitude to radians
    $lat1 = deg2rad($point1[1]);
    $lon1 = deg2rad($point1[0]);
    $lat2 = deg2rad($point2[1]);
    $lon2 = deg2rad($point2[0]);

    // Earth radius in meters
    $earthRadius = 6371000;

    // Calculate bearing from point1 to point2
    $deltaLon = $lon2 - $lon1;
    $y = sin($deltaLon) * cos($lat2);
    $x = cos($lat1) * sin($lat2) - sin($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($deltaLon);
    $bearing = atan2($y, $x);
    echo $bearing.'<br/>';
    if ($bearing>0) { 
        $aroundCorner=true;
    }

    // Convert bearing to initial azimuth
    $azimuth = ($bearing + 2 * M_PI) % (2 * M_PI);

    // Convert distance to radians
    $distanceRad = $distance / $earthRadius;

    // Calculate latitude and longitude of the new point
    $newLat = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($distanceRad) + cos($lat1) * sin($distanceRad) * cos($azimuth));
    $newLon = $lon1 + atan2(sin($azimuth) * sin($distanceRad) * cos($lat1), cos($distanceRad) - sin($lat1) * sin($newLat));

    // Convert latitude and longitude back to degrees
    $newLat = rad2deg($newLat);
    $newLon = rad2deg($newLon);

    // Determine if the new point is on the correct side of the waypoint
    $crossProduct = sin($lon2 - $lon1) * cos($newLat);
    if ($crossProduct < 0) {
        $newBearing = ($azimuth - M_PI) % (2 * M_PI);
        $newLat = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($distanceRad) + cos($lat1) * sin($distanceRad) * cos($newBearing));
        $newLon = $lon1 + atan2(sin($newBearing) * sin($distanceRad) * cos($lat1), cos($distanceRad) - sin($lat1) * sin($newLat));
        $newLat = rad2deg($newLat);
        $newLon = rad2deg($newLon);
    }

    return [$newLat, $newLon,$aroundCorner];
}

// Polygon sample
$wayline  = [
   [ 51.106383112, 3.503930725], 
   [ 51.106378907, 3.503908586], 
   [ 51.106360783, 3.503672366], 
   [ 51.106356148, 3.503569505],
   [ 51.106356295, 3.503519129], 
   [ 51.10636004, 3.503467953], 
   [ 51.106378471, 3.503347383], 
   [ 51.106384066, 3.503297128],
   [ 51.106407317, 3.503124894], 
   [ 51.106418658, 3.502982908],
   [ 51.106422361, 3.50289805], 
   [ 51.10644914,  3.502897037],
   [ 51.106445405, 3.502985213], 
   [ 51.106433893, 3.503130216], 
   [ 51.106386066, 3.503478017], 
   [ 51.106382742, 3.503525883],
   [ 51.106382876, 3.503572303], 
   [ 51.106387524, 3.503669887], 
   [ 51.106405447, 3.503902831], 
   [ 51.106409402, 3.503922577]

];

$distance = 1.5; // Distance in meters

$numPoints = count($wayline);
$newPoints = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $numPoints - 1; $i++) {
    $point1 = $wayline[$i];
    $point2 = $wayline[$i+1];
    $newPoint = calculatePoint($point1, $point2, $distance);
    $newPoints[] = $newPoint;
}

// Output the new points
foreach ($newPoints as $point) {
    if ($point[2]==false)
    {
        echo $point[1] . ',' . $point[0] . ',0<br/>';
    }
    
}
```

outputs the following :
[KML imported into google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gafr7.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to find the "visual" center of an irregularly shaped polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203135/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-visual-center-of-an-irregularly-shaped-pol) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3

Comment: This suggested answer is about the actual center of the polygon, not a centerline.

Comment: If one point is missing, does it work out if you delete or interpolate one?

Comment: I guess that's the whole point. In a straight polygon (more a rectangled shape) , the number of coordinates are always even, and right next to each other. In these cases i can make a simple centerpoint between those two coordinates and use them as waypoint. When the polygon gets a shape like show in the above image, the number of points can be odd, no knowing who's next to each other. , so not knowing which one to choose as 'closest neighbour' . I hope i make myself clear enough about this issue.

Comment: I would calculate the distance between them and interpolate the widest and a new point between. Then the number is even and you can use your same method, again.

Comment: That's indeed good thinking , i'll give it a try.