# To get larger polygon from existing polygon

Tags: image, opencv, geometry

[image]

I want to get red polygon from black polygon in OpenCV. to get larger one from existing polygon? Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeking is the *offset polygon*.  It was addressed in an earlier question,
"[An algorithm for inflating/deflating (offsetting, buffering) polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons)."
It is not easy to compute in general, but it is well-studied.