# Java 2D Polygon outside another

Tags: graphics2d, affinetransform

I'd like to know if there is a java way to, given a polygon, draw another one at a given distance and with the same center.

I tried AffineTransform but don't really know how it Works.

Thank you.

Comment: g2.translate(x,y); g2.draw(polygon) might be simpler than using a transform matrix, if you are only interested in translation.

Comment: John, sorry, I wasn´t clear enough. The idea is to build a second polygon outside from another one, but using the same center and twice the size.
Thank you.

Comment: g2.scale(2,2); g2.draw(polygon); in that case. You use AffineTransform   and a transform matrix when you want to combine translate, scale, shear, rotate and flip in one operation.

Comment: John, this is my code
        ..........p.addPoint(xx0, yy0);
        p.addPoint(xx1, yy1);
        p.addPoint(xx2, yy2);
        
        g2d.drawPolygon(p);
        
        g2d.scale(2, 2);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.drawPolygon(p);.........

What it does is to paint 2 polygons, one twice the size of the other, but the small one is not inside the big one.


Sorry about the code format, but I tried to format it and I couldn't

Comment: I have posted an answer that I think will do what you want.

Comment: Hi John, Just to let you know that your code did work very well. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure why I deleted it. I undeleted it, should you wish to accept it. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate your polygon by half its centroid width and height. I have included the code that comes from http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/PolygonUtilities.java to calculate the centroid of a polygon.

```
public void drawPolygon(){
   Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
   Polygon poly=new Polygon();
   poly.addPoint(100, 100);
   poly.addPoint(200, 100);
   poly.addPoint(200, 200);
   poly.addPoint(150, 250);
   poly.addPoint(100, 200);
   poly.addPoint(100, 100);

   g2.setColor(Color.blue);
   g2.fillPolygon(poly);        
   g2.setColor(Color.red);

   Point2D.Double []pts=new Point2D.Double[poly.npoints];

   for (int i=0;i<poly.npoints;i++){
       pts[i]=new Point2D.Double(poly.xpoints[i],poly.ypoints[i]);            
   }

   Point2D centroid=centerOfMass(pts);

   g2.translate(-centroid.getX(), -centroid.getY());
   g2.scale(2, 2);

   g2.drawPolygon(poly);        
}  

public static double area(Point2D[] polyPoints) {
   int i, j, n = polyPoints.length;
   double area = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      j = (i + 1) % n;
      area += polyPoints[i].getX() * polyPoints[j].getY();
      area -= polyPoints[j].getX() * polyPoints[i].getY();
   }
   area /= 2.0;
   return (area);
}

/**
 * Function to calculate the center of mass for a given polygon, according
 * to the algorithm defined at
 * http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/polyarea/
 * 
 * @param polyPoints
 * array of points in the polygon
 * @return point that is the center of mass
 */

public static Point2D centerOfMass(Point2D[] polyPoints) {
  double cx = 0, cy = 0;
  double area = area(polyPoints);
  // could change this to Point2D.Float if you want to use less memory
  Point2D res = new Point2D.Double();
  int i, j, n = polyPoints.length;
  double factor = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      j = (i + 1) % n;
      factor = (polyPoints[i].getX() * polyPoints[j].getY()
            - polyPoints[j].getX() * polyPoints[i].getY());
      cx += (polyPoints[i].getX() + polyPoints[j].getX()) * factor;
      cy += (polyPoints[i].getY() + polyPoints[j].getY()) * factor;
  }
  area *= 6.0f;
  factor = 1 / area;
  cx *= factor;
  cy *= factor;
  res.setLocation(cx, cy);
  return res;
}
```

Another way of doing this, common in the GIS world, is to buffer a polygon. There is a library called [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) that will provide this functionality, although it might be harder to figure out what the scale factor is.

There are some very interesting discussions about polygon growing in this post: [An algorithm for inflating/deflating (offsetting, buffering) polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons)