# Polygon Offset in three.js

Tags: three.js, polygon, offset

I want to implement polygon offset for ShapeGeometries (2D) in three.js

[image]

The above picture is an example of how it works in [CityEngine](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/manual/cga/basics/toc.html).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**UPDATE 1**

The problem is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons?rq=1). However, the external C++/C#/Delphi library **Clipper** is used to solve the problem there. It seems like the best solution is to feed a 3rd party library with the polygon values and import the result back as three.js geometry.

Comment: Sorry; I'm unclear — do the negative offsets amount to weird tessellations? Or is any area lost? The output object is still 2d, right?

Comment: Well, I dont have any implementation, but I want a `x pixel` offset for an existing 2D-Geometry. The tesselation is a problem though, because in three.js there are only triangles and I can't figure out how to implement this offset. The result is 2D again, exactly.

Comment: other than writing your own modeling tool, doubt that this is easy to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ending up feeding my 2D vertices to the Javascript version of Clipper: [Javascript Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/). It works pretty good, though there is some overhead with format conversion.

1. Convert to **Javascript Clipper** format
2. Execute offset operation in **Javascript Clipper**
3. Convert back to **three.js** format