# Enlarge (buffer) a rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Given a RotatedRect created around features using

```
rect = minAreaRect(points)
```

I would like that rectangle to be enlarged uniformly to produce a larger one, just as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons). Since this is just a rectangle and not an arbitrary polygon it won't be too difficult to create a function for this but I'm hoping there is a standard way to do this in OpenCV since it seems like a useful function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RotatedRect class contains fields: angle, center and size. Just increase size as you need.