# How to find the coodinates of the bounding rectangle from four circles around the vertices of an existing bounding rectangle

Tags: python, geometry, gis, latitude-longitude, computational-geometry

I have a bounding box which I have created. I know the lat lon of the four vertices of the box. On these vertices I have created a buffer circle of radius 10m and now I want to calculate a new bounding box which covers these four circles.

I have created four circles where I know the lat,lon of each points which makes the circle. How can I make and find the coordinates of the 4 ends of this new rectangle/bounding box which encloses these four circles in python.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTYlu.png)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear; in addition, it looks like a maths problem, not a coding one.

Comment: The math is enough to change them into code.

Answer (score 1):

For lat/lon aligned rectangle 10m distance correspond to angular shift

```
ltdiff = 180 * 10 / 20 000 000  = 0.00009
```

degrees along latitude

and

```
lndiff = 180 * 10 / 20 000 000 / cos(lat)  = 0.00009/cos(lat)
```

degrees along longitude

For example, for latitude 45n:

```
lndiff = 0.00009/cos(45) = 0.00009/0.7071 = 0.0001273 degrees
```

So expand you rectangle by these values (for small rectangles top and bottom latitude is nearly the same, so you can use the same value for cosine)

```
newtopleft.lat = topleft.lat - 0.00009 
newtopleft.lon = topleft.lon - 0.00009/cos(topleft.lat)

newtopright.lat = topright.lat - 0.00009 
newtopright.lon = topright.lon + 0.00009/cos(topright.lat)

similar for bottom left and right
```

Comment: But how can I find the coordinates of this new rectangle ?

Comment: new coordinates added

Comment: Let's say that the top coord is (74.23,6.45), for the newtop we should negate both Lat and Lon value with 0.0009. Am I right ?

Comment: No. If latitude 74.23  contains fractional degrees, then newtop = 74.23-0.00009=74.22991. Lon value will be changed by 0.00009/cos(74.23) = 0.00009/0.27= 0.00033 degrees

Comment: Could you also explain how I can acheive 4 lat,lon pairs from these. I am not able to understand. Sorry.  Let us say this is my lats [54.9,
 54.90,
 54.913,
 54.9138,
 54.919] and lon [6.313,
 6.311,
 6.314,
 6.316,
 6.313].

Comment: but why 5 values?

Comment: The first lat and the last lat was same in the above comment. How can we calculate for lats [54.9, 54.90, 54.913, 54.9138] and lon [6.313, 6.311, 6.314, 6.316]

Comment: What is unclear yet?

Comment: What values would be top,left,bottom,right. Are we using only 2 lat,lon here ? Because we have the 4 lat,lon of the bounding rectangle known.

Comment: Take lat and lon of topleft vertice. Subtract 0.00009 from it's lat, subtract 0.00009/cos(topleft.lat) from it's lon. Do similar calculations with other vertices.

Comment: What can be done if the given shape is not a rectangle but a parallelogram or a simple qaudrilateral ? Could you guide me into some resources.

Comment: [For plane geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68109283/844416). For spherical coordinates bisectors should be calculated in more complex way. But your question was about rectangle. If you are using some gis/geo library, it might contain functions for offset polygon calculation.