# Expanding a radius around a polygon of lat/long for X miles

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

I'm working on a project which requires me to build a function to expand a polygon of long/lat in a distance of X miles to create a "border".

[image: Example of border around a polygon to X number of miles]

The technology i am using is JavaScript deskgl / nebula gl layers. And i am unsure whether javascript deskgl/nebula gl has the built in ability to perform these operations. If not, this leads me to question the maths behind this functionality.

As i am unfamiliar with long an lat on a 2d plane, nor whether the stack i am using can deal with this, how do i go about expanding an array of arrays (long, lat) by X number of miles.

Comment: Are the polygons necessarily convex? Otherwise the algorithm is pretty complicated.

Comment: If the polygons can be any (simple) polygon check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons. There are some answers for JS included.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [ScaleMode in Nebula](https://nebula.gl/docs/api-reference/modes/overview), it allows you to click and then drag a polygon and keeps it's shape. If you need to be able to do that by a specific distance, you could look into their implementation of scaling and you could adapt that.