# Scaling a set of coordinates which define an irregular shape in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a very irregular shape in the form of vectors for x and y coordinates that I want to scale down. But I want the scaled-down shape to stay within the boundaries of the original shape. I thought just doing `x_scaled = s * x` and `y_scaled = s * y` would do the trick but this is what I get when I do that :-

[image]

As you can see the scaled-down shape crosses the boundaries of the original at multiple points. I would like for it to be completely contained inside the original shape. What I want would be something similar to this (not accurate, just a representation I tried making in photopea) -

[image]

The representation I made is not very good but I hope it helps get my point across. I just want the scaled-down shapeto be fully inside. And I am not sure how to do that. The language I am using is MATLAB but if I can just understand the logic I should be able to implement it.

Comment: This is not a simple problem. You are asking for an inward offset polygon, not a scaling. You can find this question asked [here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons

Comment: You cannot do this with scaling and translation alone. Offsetting would get you a polygon that is inside the original one, but it would have a different shape, and could even be cut into multiple polygons. I like using the Clipper library in C++ for this. Someone has already linked this library to MATLAB: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61329-new-polygon-clipping-and-offsetting

Comment: [`imerode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) on the interior of the shape would probably work.

Comment: I did it with imerode in the end

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `bwmorph` to capture 1-pixel depth surface of the shape to shrink, with for instance

```
A2 = bwmorph(A1,'remove');
```

`A` has to be `[0 1]` single layer figure, not an RGB picture.

**2.** Get the coordinates `[x1 y1]` or linear index `n1` to all white pixels in `A2`

[x1 y1] are coordinates for all surface pixels.

**3.** Remove `[x1 y1]` pixels in `A1`

**4.** Repeat to reach desired depth

Eventually, if 'pealing' deep enough the obtained figure reaches the same result as using command `bwskel` that skeletonizes input figures.