# Seeking Algorithm for Generating Non-Overlapping Polygons from Path Segments for Pattern Filling

Tags: algorithm, rust, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm in search of an algorithm that can accept a series of vertices (e.g., v1, v2, v3, ...) defining a path, along with a specified line width, and generate a polygon for each path segment (like v1 to v2). The key requirement is that these polygons should not overlap each other. In cases where overlapping might occur, the areas should be distributed evenly across the relevant segments. The purpose behind this is to draw a pattern along the path, filling each segment's polygon with a pattern that is appropriately rotated and translated to fit.

I have developed a [preliminary solution in Rust](https://github.com/FreemapSlovakia/rustmap/blob/fd59ec0ed5ba1f511483c28e4d4782f460a954c4/src/line_pattern.rs). However, I've noticed that it struggles with certain edge cases.

Additionally, the solution should account for line joins (bevel, miter) and a miter limit. I'm open to implementations in any practical programming language. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: While I think this is an interesting geometry problem, one which I have faced myself, I don't believe that this question, as written, is appropriate for SO. I would suggest that you focus on: one specific type of edge case, AND the code which you have written to try to handle that edge case, which does not work.

Comment: ... that said, your approach of "evenly distributed" to neighbouring segments seems to be an attempt to preserve the total area of the resulting geometry. But consider a polygon which is like a tightly coiled spiral, with very small gap between each concentric circle. There is definitely no way to maintain a specified line width. Consider how your algorithm behaves for that (very much degenerate) case - how you handle that will apply very well to the case you find in the bottom left of your picture.

Comment: I would suggest creating some kind of spatial data structure like an r-tree. Put the points in the r-tree. Put the lines in the same tree. Create a way to represent a shaded area and add that to the tree. Then divide the shaded area up according o which line segment it is closest to. That division will be your answer.

Comment: Have you looked at algorithms for the Minkowski sum of non-convex polygons? With a bit of digging you may find an algorithm. (https://bjpcjp.github.io/pdfs/math/minkowski-sum-ADM.pdf) Do you want to generate only convex non-overlapping polygons, or just non-overlapping polygons? Also, I assume you've looked at libraries like "Clipper 2" mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons?rq=2