Contour Parrallele ToolPath Finding
I am very interested these days in the generation of filling paths on closed contours, with the aim of programming these algorithms in unity
I already have an algorithm on Unity where I can draw a contour (it can be open or closed) and create a simple tool path taking into account the diameter of the tool my algorithm also takes into account the areas of the contour where the tool cannot reach without going beyond the contour
my Unity algo
this example represent my algo, the red dot are my contour, and in purple, the tool path
my algorithm also takes into account the areas of the contour where the tool cannot reach without going beyond the contour
enter image description here
I would like to be able to generate a toolpath that fills the entire contour, as shown in the following example
enter image description here
my source code
hoping that you can guide me
cordially Baptist

After a few days of additional research, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons
